# getting an error "no match for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++

I'm working on a task and I made a function. I wanted to check if it does what I want it to but I'm getting an error in the 27th line which says:

```
|27|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'int [40]')|
```

I don't know how to fix it and would appreciate any answers. Here's my work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int k[96], t[40], zaidnez[40];
int n, zaide = 0, nezaide = 0;

void skaitymas();
//void didziausias();
//void spausdinimas();

int main(){
    skaitymas();
    cout << k[1] << " " << t << " " << zaidnez[1];

return 0;
}

void skaitymas()
{
    ifstream fd ("u1.txt");
    fd >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fd >> k[i] >> t;
        for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
            fd >> zaidnez[j];
        }
    }
    fd.close;
}
```

Comment: `fd >> k[i] >> t`... Don't you mean `t[i]`?

Comment: You may want to consider using one array of a structure that contains `k,t,` and `zaidnez`.

Comment: I feel so stupid... thanks